# DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Failed to connect error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am running a hub and a node locally (A), and a node from another pc(B). This is how i run scripts locally (A) http://prntscr.com/pghnwk  , and this is how i run the script in B computer http://prntscr.com/pghox4 . The code in node scripts are the same , only browsers differ. But, when i'm accessing localhost:4443/grid/console , I get this http://prntscr.com/pghr87

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the host IP/Name using **-host** option while registering from pc(B). While running node from the virtual machine, the advertised IP address seems wrong (May be IP address of host machine of VM). Please check that IP address.

For help on the node role

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -help
Usage: <main class> [options]
  Options:
    --version, -version
       Displays the version and exits.
       Default: false
    -browserTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to
       hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If the
       timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the session
       will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means
       wait indefinitely.
       Default: 0
    -capabilities, -browser
       <String> : comma separated Capability values. Example: -capabilities
       browserName=firefox,platform=linux -capabilities browserName=chrome,platform=linux
       Default: [Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5}], Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5}], Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=internet explorer, maxInstances=1}]]
    -cleanUpCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies
       for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option
    -custom
       <String> : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions.
       NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: -custom
       myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2
       Default: {}
    -debug
       <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
       Default: false
    -downPollingLimit
       <Integer> : node is marked as "down" if the node hasn't responded after
       the number of checks specified in [downPollingLimit].
       Default: 2
    -host
       <String> IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most commonly
       useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN)
    -hub
       <String> : the url that will be used to post the registration request.
       This option takes precedence over -hubHost and -hubPort options.
       Default: http://localhost:4444
    -hubHost
       <String> IP or hostname : the host address of the hub we're attempting to
       register with. If -hub is specified the -hubHost is determined from it.
    -hubPort
       <Integer> : the port of the hub we're attempting to register with. If
       -hub is specified the -hubPort is determined from it.
    -id
       <String> : optional unique identifier for the node. Defaults to the url
       of the remoteHost, when not specified.
    -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
       <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
       negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
    -log
       <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log
       to STDOUT
    -maxSession
       <Integer> max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node,
       irrespective of the browser used
       Default: 5
    -nodeConfig
       <String> filename : JSON configuration file for the node. Overrides
       default values
    -nodePolling
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll to see if the
       node is still responding.
       Default: 5000
    -nodeStatusCheckTimeout
       <Integer> in ms : connection/socket timeout, used for node "nodePolling"
       check.
       Default: 5000
    -port
       <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
       Default: 5555
    -proxy
       <String> : the class used to represent the node proxy. Default is
       [org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy].
       Default: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
    -register
       if specified, node will attempt to re-register itself automatically with
       its known grid hub if the hub becomes unavailable.
       Default: true
    -registerCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the node will try to register
       itself again. Allows administrator to restart the hub without restarting (or
       risk orphaning) registered nodes. Must be specified with the "-register"
       option.
       Default: 5000
    -role
       <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
       Default: node
    -servlet, -servlets
       <String> : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make
       available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet tld.company.ServletA
       -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must exist in the path:
       /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB
       Default: []
    -timeout, -sessionTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
       automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X seconds. The
       test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typically
       used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycle
       must also be set.
       Default: 1800
    -unregisterIfStillDownAfter
       <Integer> in ms : if the node remains down for more than
       [unregisterIfStillDownAfter] ms, it will stop attempting to re-register from the hub.
       Default: 60000
    -withoutServlet, -withoutServlets
       <String> : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced
       use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify multiple on
       the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA -withoutServlet
       tld.company.ServletB
       Default: []
```